# Tuning RPS in Linux kernel decreases performance

Tags: linux, performance, networking, linux-kernel

I'm trying to tune RPS in the kernel by writing to the `rps_cpus` file, but instead of seeing an increase in performance, it is decreasing.

I have 28 CPU cores that are divided between two NUMA nodes. NUMA node 0 contain even CPU core numbers, that are also isolated on the system. NUMA node 1 is uneven CPU cores. I am using a traffic generator on core 4,6,8 and running a forwarding application with `taskset` on CPU core 12 so it is bound to that core. I have 4 receive queues in total.

From what I have seen in the documentation a bitmask of CPUs is set to indicate the CPUs that can process packets and you should bind each queue to a separate CPU core that is close to the core processing the packet or the CPU core that is processing the packet.

I have tried multiple times to bind it to cores on the same NUMA node. For example, I wanted to bind receive queues to CPU cores`2,10,12,14` so I converted `101010000000100` into decimal `21508` and wrote it to all queues (`rx-0, rx-1, rx-2, rx-3`).

```
echo 21508 > /sys/class/net/eth0/queues/rx-0/rps_cpus
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/queues/rx-0/rps_cpus  --->  0020008
```

I have also tried this for only core `12`, and only core `12` and `2`. But whatever I choose the result remains the same. That is the performance decrease and there is a large increase in latency.

What CPU or CPUs should I bind when using RPS? And what should I write to the `rps_cpu` file?
I have seen people mentioning that you can write hex values to the file, but this is not possible on my system as a get `Invalid argument` then. I am on kernel version `6.1.9`.

Comment: Did you note that the for default for non-RPS is that the packet is handled by the same CPU that receives the interrupt? Why would getting two different CPUs involved improve performance?